# .focus not staying put

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I have a validation routine I keep in my SSJS script library. It gets called when I hit the save button. The purpose (as seen in several posts around here) is to perform form validation, creates the error messages, then the onClientLoad event will display the message and return focus to the first problem field it finds.

Here are the code snippets; From the SSJS script library:

```js
function DBValidate(FormName:String) {
 var efn:string = null;  // error Field Name
 var errorMessages:String = null;
 
 // here is where we group validation by the calling form.
 switch (FormName) {
  case "FieldDef":
  if ( isEmpty(currentDocument.getItemValue("FormName")[0]) ) setError("FormName","Form name cannot be blank");
  if ( isEmpty(currentDocument.getItemValue("EnglishFormName")[0]) ) setError("EnglishFormName","English form name cannot be blank");
  break
  default:
 }
 // We built the error messages (All will be displayed in a promptbox in the onClientLoad event 
 // of the form) The form MUST have an ErrorMessage field because we embed carriage returns 
 // in the message and viewScope.get doesn't like those too much..... We can however pass 
 // the error field(for focus if I ever get that working.....)in a viewScope variable.
 getComponent("ErrorMessage").setValue(errorMessages);
 viewScope.put("errorField",efn);
 if (errorMessages == null ) {
  return true;
 } else { 
  return false;
 }
}
function setError(fName:string,emsg:string){
 // after failing a field validation in DBValidate we
 // make note of the field name and build the error message that
 // we're going to display in the onClientLoad event.
 // Make note of the first field ID to fail so we can
 // set focus to it.
 if (efn==null) efn=getClientId(fName);
 if (errorMessages == null) {
  errorMessages = String.fromCharCode(10) + emsg;
 } else {
  errorMessages += String.fromCharCode(10) + emsg;
 }
 return
}
```

```html
 <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false"
  refreshMode="norefresh">
  <xp:this.script>
   <![CDATA[
    // the DBValidation routine sets the ErrorMessage computed field to something
    // if there was an error. If we had one, then we display a message, extract the field
    // name from the message.
    var em = XSP.getElementById("#{id:ErrorMessage}").innerHTML;
    if (em.length > 0) { 
     alert(em);
     var efn = '#{javascript:viewScope.get("errorField")}';
     var ef = dojo.byId(efn);
     ef.focus();
    }
   ]]>
  </xp:this.script>
 </xp:eventHandler>
```

The ef.focus() actually works. I can see the cursor flash into the first field that has the error, but then it goes away.

I have no idea what's causing this. I try to follow in the debugger, but after stepping out of the onClientLoad event, I start wandering into very dense code (the upper piece which shows the UI is grayed out so I really can't tell when focus gets applied then removed. I don't have any other events defined.

Comment: If you have two or more errors, does it try to cycle through all of them?(even  very quickly)

Comment: It cycles through any errors storing the error messages in the errorMessages field. In the setError routine I get the id of the first field in which we encounter the error in the "efn" field which I get in my onClientLoad event by getting the viewScope variable. Debugger is showing I'm returning the correct field and the focus command is working, I see the vertical black cursor line appear in that field momentarily, but then it disappears. Something is happening after the onClientLoad event

Comment: just for fun, try adding the line "return false" after your if statement

Comment: Is your code in the "Client" onClientLoad or the "Server" onClientLoad?  It looks to be in the Server side but XSP.getElementByID is clientside. I never tried it, but I don't think the XSP class and methods work in SSJS.

Comment: Did you intend to add this to the Client side, and accidentally put in the Server side, that is easy to do??

Comment: The onClientLoad event is client-sided code. The value of "em" is returned faithfully. I placed a return false after the ef.focus() line and now it's working. Would you like to respond to this as an answer so I can mark it answered and upvote it? - Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I am glad that worked.  I will add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `return false` after the `ef.focus()` line. This will cease execution of any serverside code from running immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues where some "under the hood Dojo magic" is going on - and therefore moves the focus.

The way I have gotten around it is a little "hack" where I use a client side timeout function to delay setting the focus 100-200 ms.

Not ideal, but I gave up trying to make it work directly ;-)

/John

Comment: I replaced the code with; setTimeout(function(){ef.focus()},300). I don't think this is it. Previous attempts, I hard coded the field name instead of using a dojo function. Same result.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok. It was just a quick try then ;-)